# Two votes on this question to close as “not programming related” – how best to respond, as the asker?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I asked this clearly programming-related question: [Smart pointer analog of `std::shared_ptr` with API to bind callbacks to refcount-modifying events e.g. release/retain … is this a thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283409/smart-pointer-analog-of-stdshared-ptr-with-api-to-bind-callbacks-to-refcount)

… which has been met with two close-votes, both as “not programming related”. I really don’t quite know how to respond to that, because the programming-relatedness of the question is bogglingly evident to me. Plus, the explanation of this particular close-vote category that you see in the close-vote modal popup cites SO guidelines which are also evidently not in violation.

This is a bit frustrating, as an honest asker of questions – what is the proper protocol in this case, from my end?

EDIT: I have edited the original question as per the suggestions in the answer given below. TIL of the ire that triggering phraseology can invoke, indeed!

Comment: Actually, the close vote reason they chose is "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." That's part of the "within the scope defined in the help center" section of the off-topic description.

Comment: But I’m not just saying “who’s got a smart pointer snippet?” … I am trying to solve a problem but I am not ruling out the fact that it may have already been neatly solved by those who have come before me – q.v. the only answer thus far proposes an implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two trigger phrases here would explain why those who voted to close did so with the reason they chose:

> I am looking for a smart-pointer structure – analogous to std::shared_ptr – that offers me some kind of API...
>
> ...I’m not familiar with the landscape beyond std, so recommendations are welcome...

If you're trying to make the case that this question isn't asking for a recommendation of some kind of third-party library or resource explicitly, these two phrases would be a good place to start.

Comment: Aha OK I see, I appreciate your guidance on my language here. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks again, I’ve edited these trigger phrases – I guess we see what happens now, I suppose. Good chance it’ll still go to closeville I would wager but hey, you win or you learn